# Find the Value segment after a field segment in PHP xml

Tags: php, xml

I need to get the value(1250) of the value segment after the field segment with a value of "Bottle Number", using PHP.  Here is a snippet of the xml...

```
<CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
      <Field>1</Field>
      <Value>1</Value>
      <DateSaved>2013-11-15T12:21:35</DateSaved>
      <SourceType />
      <SourceID />
    </CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
    <CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
      <Field>Bottle Number</Field>
      <Value>1250</Value>
      <DateSaved>2013-12-11T15:22:34</DateSaved>
      <SourceType />
      <SourceID />
    </CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
    <CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
      <Field>City</Field>
      <Value>Heath</Value>
      <DateSaved>2013-12-11T15:22:34</DateSaved>
      <SourceType />
      <SourceID />
    </CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) I get lots of hits from simply googling PHP XML. In any case take a look at [this](http://php.net/simplexml)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse it with **[SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)**.

I share with you 2 approaches, first with index and second iterative.

Before to parse your XML, you should envolve it within a root element (any name), I added XML info (version) too.

```
<?php
$input = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
<CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
 <Field>1</Field>
 <Value>1</Value>
 <DateSaved>2013-11-15T12:21:35</DateSaved>
 <SourceType />
 <SourceID />
</CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
<CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
 <Field>Bottle Number</Field>
 <Value>1250</Value>
 <DateSaved>2013-12-11T15:22:34</DateSaved>
 <SourceType />
 <SourceID />
</CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
<CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
 <Field>City</Field>
 <Value>Heath</Value>
 <DateSaved>2013-12-11T15:22:34</DateSaved>
 <SourceType />
 <SourceID />
</CustomerRecordExtraInfo>
</root>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($input);

// Approach 1 - index
echo $xml->CustomerRecordExtraInfo[1]->Value;

// Approach 2 - iterative
foreach($xml->CustomerRecordExtraInfo as $customer) {
  if($customer->Field == "Bottle Number") {
    echo $customer->Value;
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `xpath`, a 'query-language' for XML:

```
// $xml holds the simplexml object
$result = $xml->xpath("//CustomerRecordExtraInfo[Field = 'Bottle Number']");
echo $result[0]->Value;
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pp7IBJ

Answer (score 0):

Xpath allows you to use expressions to extract data from an XML. DOMXpath::evaluate() is the most flexible function in PHP to use it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//CustomerRecordExtraInfo[Field = "Bottle Number"]/Value)')
);
```

Get all CustomerRecordExtraInfo elements anywhere in the document:

`//CustomerRecordExtraInfo`

Only if the have a child element "Field" with the the text content "Bottle Number"

`//CustomerRecordExtraInfo[Field = "Bottle Number"]`

Get the child element "Value" the found nodes

`//CustomerRecordExtraInfo[Field = "Bottle Number"]/Value`

And cast it into string (number is possible, too)

`string(//CustomerRecordExtraInfo[Field = "Bottle Number"]/Value)`